# Как сделать выбор из таблицы?

Tags: c#, asp.net, реестр

Здравствуйте.

Я делаю вывод строки из таблицы, на которую нажал в textbox.  Я это попытался сделать, но выходит ошибка

> "Недействительный аргумент обратной
> передачи или обратного вызова. 
> Проверка события включена с помощью
> <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
> в конфигурации или <%@ Page
> EnableEventValidation="true" %> на
> странице"

Как убрать эту ошибку, не используя `EnableEventValidation="true"`, а через `RegisterForEventValidation`?

Asp.net framework 2.0 c#

Мой код:

```
// Нажатие на кнопку вывода таблицы  
public void FindAdr_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
adres_data.SelectParameters.Remove(adres_data.SelectParameters["ul"]);
adres_data.SelectParameters.Add("ul", adr_name.Text.ToString());
adres_data.SelectParameters["ul"].DefaultValue = adr_name.Text.ToString();

 }  
//событие RowDataBound  
 protected void adrTabl_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
              LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
              string _jsSingle = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton,                      "Select$"  + e.Row.RowIndex);
       e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "hand";
      e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = _jsSingle;
    e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
    e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
             }
            }
            }  
        // На выбор строки  
        protected void adrTabl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          GridViewRow selectedRow = adrTabl.SelectedRow;
            adres.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text + ",," + selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            adresF.Text = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text + ",," + selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

        }
```

Comment: было бы неплохо, если бы ваш код отформатировали

Comment: @DreamChild отформатировал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        adres_data.SelectParameters.Add("ul", adr_name.Text.ToString());
        ds_mkb.SelectParameters.Add("nameds", "%" + mkb_name.Text.ToString() + "%");
        ds_katl.SelectParameters.Add("nemka", katnamed.Text.ToString());
    }
}
```

Render :

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
       foreach (GridViewRow r in adrTabl.Rows)
       {
           if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
               LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)r.Cells[0].Controls[0];

               string _jsSingle = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "Select$" + r.RowIndex);

               r.Style["cursor"] = "hand";
               r.Attributes["onclick"] = _jsSingle;

               r.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
               r.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
               ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(((LinkButton)r.Cells[0].Controls[0]).UniqueID, "Select$" + r.RowIndex);
}
        base.Render(writer);
    }

           }
```